# I need to make a function that takes a body of text and outputs a list of all unique words in the text. The output list will contain strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, computer-science

Here is what I got. It is not working when I run it. Can someone help guide me on what is wrong with my code?

```
def unique_words(text : str) ->list:
  text = open(text, 'r')
  text_contents = text.read()
  text.close()
  word_list = text_contents.split()

word = open(str, 'w')
unique = []
for word in word_list:
    if word not in word_list:
        file.append(str(word) + "\n")
```

unique.sort()

return(unique)

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wukhc.png)

Comment: If you're going to post Python code, you need to reproduce your indentation accurately. Otherwise readers need to guess which problems are the problems you want to ask about, and which problems you have introduced by messing up the indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set will hold all unique values. If you add duplicate, then the set will ignore it.

```
word_list = ['hello', 'hello', 'world', 'world']

unique = set()
for word in word_list:
    if word not in unique:
        unique.add(word)
print(unique)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use set() to return unique values and delete duplicate